# Automapper: How to ignore a member in VB.NET

Tags: automapper

I'm using Automapper in a VB.NET project, and am trying to make it ignore a member.  I can see how to do this in C#, but not in VB.NET.  Does anyone have a quick example of using the ForMember method.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Which version of VB.NET?

Comment: The VB.NET that comes with VS2010 - never really considered its version number!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you do it :)

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Of incomingModel, outgoingModel)().ForMember(Function(x) x.FieldToIgnore, Sub(y) y.Ignore())
```

The thing that is important, and likely what messed up you is the **Sub** instead of the **function** for the second part.

this also only works in vs2010.  older versions you can't do it.

Comment: Amazing ! Sub instead of Function ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is now (AutoMapper 2.0) an IgnoreMap attribute.